# Compare two directories to check which files are missing on the destination path with Robocopy?

Tags: command-line, file-transfer, robocopy

I have two directories with the same name and same sub-folder names.

I am running this command:

```
ROBOCOPY “Source 1” “Source 2” *.* /L /NJH /NJS /NP /NS /log:reconcile.txt
```

But it shows me new files from Source 1 which are already been moved to Source 2.

Answer (score 0):

Those parameters all look good.

Are Source 1 and Source 2 both on the same system?

If not, then take a close look at the date and times on both systems in case a discrepancy there is confusing Robocopy.